# Does this inequality hold true, in general?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, functional-inequalities

Let

$$N = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$

be the *prime* factorization of the positive integer $N$.

Does the following inequality hold true in general?

$$\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{\frac{p_i}{p_i - 1}} < \frac{2\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{p_i}}{1 + \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{p_i}}$$

If not, for what particular values of $N$ does this inequality hold?

Note that $\omega(N)$ denotes the number of *distinct* prime factors of $N$.

Comment: [Please see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Thanks @ZevChonoles, that is noted!  =)

Comment: Please refer to this [newer MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462307) for more details.

Comment: Please refer to this [related MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414663) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that
that inequality is true
about 95% of the time.

As in my previous answer,
 cancel the
numerator of each side to get
the equivalent inequality

$\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{\dfrac{1}{p_i - 1}} < \dfrac{2}{1 + \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{p_i}}
$
or
$1 + \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{p_i}
< 2\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}(p_i - 1) 
$.

Dividing by 
$\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{p_i}$,
and, using the fact that
$\dfrac{\phi(n)}{n}
=\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}\dfrac{p_i-1}{p_i}
$,
this becomes
$1+\dfrac{1}{\phi(n)}
<2\dfrac{\phi(n)}{n}
$.

Since $\dfrac{1}{\phi(n)}$
is small for large $n$,
the proportion of $n$ satisfying this
is the same as the proportion satisfying
$\frac{1}{2}
<\dfrac{\phi(n)}{n}
$,
or
$2
>\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)}
$.

At this point,
I did a Google search for
"density of euler phi function".
The second link is
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-09/S0002-9939-07-08771-0/S0002-9939-07-08771-0.pdf.
This paper,
by ANDREAS WEINGARTNER,
is titled
"THE DISTRIBUTION FUNCTIONS OF σ(n)/n AND n/ϕ(n)".
Here is its abstract:

"Let σ(n) be the sum of the positive divisors of n. We show that
the natural density of the set of integers n satisfying σ(n)/n ≥ t is given
by 
$\exp\big(−e^{t e^{−γ}(1 + O(t^{−2}))}\big)$
, where γ denotes Euler’s constant. The same
result holds when σ(n)/n is replaced by n/ϕ(n), where ϕ is Euler’s totient
function."

This paper has clearly done
the heavy lifting.
If we put $t = 2$,
and use $\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$
(I show each stage in the computation for checkability),
$te^{-\gamma} = 1.1229189671$,
$e^{te^{-\gamma}}=3.0738134815$,
$\exp(-e^{te^{-\gamma}})
=0.0462444658
$.

This is the density of $n$ for which
$\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)}
> 2
$.
The density for which
$\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)}
< 2
$
is one minus this
or $0.9537555342$.

Comment: Thank you for your very comprehensive (and interesting!) answer, @martycohen.  =)

Comment: I apologize @martycohen, but I just spotted (today) what seems to be an "error" from the inequality

$$1 + \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{p_i} < 2\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{(p_i - 1)},$$

from which we obtain, upon dividing through by $\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{p_i}$,

$$1 + \frac{1}{N} < 2\frac{\phi(N)}{N}.$$

Thus, we get the inequality

$$\frac{N}{\phi(N)} < \frac{2N}{N + 1}.$$

If $N > 1$, then

$$I(N) = \frac{\sigma(N)}{N} < \frac{N}{\phi(N)} < \frac{2N}{N + 1},$$

where $I(N)$ is the abundancy index of $x$ and $\sigma(N)$ is the sum of divisors of $N$.

Comment: This earlier [MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414663) of mine then appears relevant.

In particular, [MSE user Tharsis](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/53846/tharsis) conjectures that ${\it all}$ odd deficient numbers satisfies

$$I(N) = \frac{\sigma(N)}{N} < \frac{2N}{N + 1}.$$

Comment: Looking at your post beginning at the fourth sentence @martycohen, I can see that, since the inequality

$$I(N) = \frac{\sigma(N)}{N} < \frac{N}{\phi(N)} < \frac{2N}{N + 1} < 2$$

from my earlier comment here results to the same inequality

$$\frac{1}{2} < \frac{\phi(N)}{N}$$

from your fourth sentence in this post, the succeeding claims still hold true, I'd suppose?  =)

Comment: Please refer to this [newer MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462307) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

We can cancel the
numerator of each side to get
the equivalent inequality

$\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{\dfrac{1}{p_i - 1}} < \dfrac{2}{1 + \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{p_i}}
$
or
$1 + \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}{p_i}
< 2\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)}(p_i - 1) 
$.

Let's look at
the sum over primes
$f(x) =
\sum_{p < x} \ln (p-1)
$.
Since
$\sum_{p < x} \ln p \approx  x$
(from the prime number theorem),

$\begin{align}
f(x) 
&=\sum_{p < x} \ln (p-1)\\
&=\sum_{p < x} (\ln p+\ln(1-1/p))\\
&=\sum_{p < x} \ln p+\sum_{p < x}\ln(1-1/p)\\
&\approx x-\sum_{p < x}(1/p+1/(2p^2)+...)\\
&\approx x-\ln \ln x+C\\
\end{align}
$

From this,
$e^{f(x)}
\approx e^{x-\ln \ln x+C}
= C_1 e^x/\ln x
$.

If 
$N(x) = \prod_{p < x} p$
and
$M(x) = \prod_{p < x} (p-1)$,
$N(x) \approx e^x$
and
$M(x) \approx C_1 e^x/\ln x$,
$1+N(x) < 2M(x)$
means,
for large enough $x$,
$e^x < C_1 e^x/\ln x$,
which is false.

So that inequality is often false.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @martycohen!  I think that your answer is somewhat inconsistent with what I was expecting, since the density of the integers that I "expect" to satisfy that inequality is a bit high - at least $\approx 0.831$, but then again, this is subject of course to an "underlying hypothesis".  Again, my profuse thanks for taking the time to answer my MSE question.  =)

Comment: BTW, it can be shown that the inequality holds for odd primes and (odd) prime powers.  It does ${\it not}$ hold for the (even) prime $2$.

Comment: Please refer to this [newer MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462307) for more details.