# What proportion of the positive integers satisfy $I(n) < \frac{2n}{n + 1} \leq I(n^2)$ < 2?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, arithmetic-functions

Let

$$I(x) = \frac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$

be the abundancy index of the positive integer $x$.  Note that $\sigma(x)$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function.  For example,

$$\sigma(12) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 12 = 28.$$

My question is this:  What proportion of the positive integers satisfy the inequality
$$I(n) < \frac{2n}{n + 1} \leq I(n^2) < 2?$$

Note that we necessarily have $n > 1$ from the left-hand inequality.

[Edit: September 10 2013] This question has already been answered by [Don](https://mathoverflow.net/users/16510) in MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141679).  Thanks everyone! [End edit]

Comment: What is the function $I$?

Comment: $I(n) = \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$?

Comment: My apologies for missing out on the definition of the function $I$.  Yes @DanielFischer, indeed it is the abundancy index function.  Editing my question to reflect that change now.

Comment: Hold on, I need to add an additional constraint.  Again, my apologies.

Comment: Done adding the constraint $I(n^2) < 2$.  This last version of the question should be final.

Comment: In case anyone is interested in further answers to this question, I have asked a similar question in MO [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141679).

Comment: This question has already been answered by [Don](http://mathoverflow.net/users/16510) in MO [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141679).  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extracted from my answer to
[Does this inequality hold true, in general?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445467/does-this-inequality-hold-true-in-general/)

Apply the result stated below
to get the results
for any constraints whatsoever.

I did a Google search for
"density of euler phi function".
The second link is
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-09/S0002-9939-07-08771-0/S0002-9939-07-08771-0.pdf.
This paper,
by ANDREAS WEINGARTNER,
is titled
"THE DISTRIBUTION FUNCTIONS OF σ(n)/n AND n/ϕ(n)".
Here is its abstract:

"Let σ(n) be the sum of the positive divisors of n. We show that
the natural density of the set of integers n satisfying σ(n)/n ≥ t is given
by 
$\exp\big(−e^{t e^{−γ}(1 + O(t^{−2}))}\big)$
, where γ denotes Euler’s constant. The same
result holds when σ(n)/n is replaced by n/ϕ(n), where ϕ is Euler’s totient
function."

Comment: Thank you for your answer @martycohen.