# What proportion of the positive integers satisfy this number-theoretic inequality?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of the divisors of the positive integer $x$, and let the *abundancy index* of $x$ be defined as

$$I(x) = \frac{\sigma(x)}{x}.$$

My question is this:  What proportion of the positive integers satisfy

$$\frac{\zeta(3)}{\zeta(2)}\cdot\frac{2n}{n + 1} < I(n) < \frac{2n}{n + 1}?$$

Note that we have the rational approximation $\zeta(3)/\zeta(2) \approx 0.7307629694$.

Comment: Helpful: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1972-26-119/S0025-5718-1972-0327700-7/S0025-5718-1972-0327700-7.pdf

Comment: Mits Kobayashi is the expert on such inequalities; I believe one of his recent papers has an algorithm for calculating the proportion you're interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll copy part of my 
(not really mine,
but I found it)
answer from here:
[Does this inequality hold true, in general?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445467/does-this-inequality-hold-true-in-general/)

I did a Google search for
"density of euler phi function".
The second link is
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-09/S0002-9939-07-08771-0/S0002-9939-07-08771-0.pdf.
This paper,
by ANDREAS WEINGARTNER,
is titled
"THE DISTRIBUTION FUNCTIONS OF σ(n)/n AND n/ϕ(n)".
Here is its abstract:

"Let σ(n) be the sum of the positive divisors of n. We show that
the natural density of the set of integers n satisfying σ(n)/n ≥ t is given
by 
$\exp\big(−e^{t e^{−γ}(1 + O(t^{−2}))}\big)$
, where γ denotes Euler’s constant. The same
result holds when σ(n)/n is replaced by n/ϕ(n), where ϕ is Euler’s totient
function."

This paper has clearly done
the heavy lifting.
If we put $t = 2$,
and use $\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$
(I show each stage in the computation for checkability),
$te^{-\gamma} = 1.1229189671$,
$e^{te^{-\gamma}}=3.0738134815$,
$\exp(-e^{te^{-\gamma}})
=0.0462444658
$.

This is the density of $n$ for which
$\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)}
> 2
$.
The density for which
$\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)}
< 2
$
is one minus this
or $0.9537555342$.

Do this for your bounds.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it ignores the error term $O(t^{-2})$, which is $O(1)$ when $t=2$. The quoted result is only non-trivial when $t\to \infty$.

Comment: It would certainly be nice if a better result could be found. Alternatively, numerical experimentation could give an empirical answer.