# Seek information on the function $f(n) =\prod_{k}\frac{p_k^{\alpha_k + 1}-1}{p_k^{\alpha_k + 1}}$

Tags: number-theory

I'm interested in any known properties of the following function over natural numbers:

$f(n) =\prod_{k}\frac{p_k^{\alpha_k + 1}-1}{p_k^{\alpha_k + 1}}$

where $ n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, is the prime factorization.

For example $f(140) = \frac{(48)(24)(2)(7)}{(49)(25)(3)(8)}=0.5485714...$

Of course $0<f(n)<1$. Has this function been studied or have a name? I realize it's similar to others but have not turned up anything in searches. Thanks.

Comment: 3 is not a divisor of 140.

Comment: If you are including $3^0$, why not include $p^0$ for all other primes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(n) 
=\prod_{k}\dfrac{p_k^{a_k + 1}-1}{p_k^{a_k + 1}}
$

If
$n
=\prod_{k}p_k^{a_k} 
$,
then
$\sigma_m(n)
=\sum_{d|n} d^m
=\prod_{k}\dfrac{p_k^{m(a_k + 1)}-1}{p_k^{m}- 1}
$
and
the totient function
$\phi(n)
=\sum_{k=1, (k, n)=1}^n 1
=n\prod_k \dfrac{p_k-1}{p_k}
$

Therefore
$\sigma(n)
=\sigma_1(n)
=\prod_{k}\dfrac{p_k^{a_k + 1}-1}{p_k- 1}
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\sigma(n)}{f(n)}
&=\prod_{k}\dfrac{p_k^{a_k + 1}}{p_k- 1}\\
&=\prod_{k}p_k^{a_k}\prod_{k}\dfrac{p_k}{p_k- 1}\\
&=n\prod_{k}\dfrac{p_k}{p_k- 1}\\
&=n\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)}\\
&=\dfrac{n^2}{\phi(n)}\\
\text{so}\\
f(n)
&=\dfrac{\sigma(n)\phi(n)}{n^2}\\
\end{array}
$

This bound is mentioned in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function
as being proved in
 Hardy & Wright 1979, thm. 436:

$\dfrac{6}{\pi^2}
\lt f(n)
\lt 1
$.

You might also find
this answer of mine relevant:

[What proportion of the positive integers satisfy this number-theoretic inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116876/what-proportion-of-the-positive-integers-satisfy-this-number-theoretic-inequalit/1117016#1117016)

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thanks.